# Responsive navigation box

Tags: javascript, css, navigationbar

I made a navigation bar with CSS animation and javascript. But I could not make it responsive. I want the navigation bar animation to be none when the window is resized less than 700px and the animation should appear if it is greater than 700px.That means the `transform`  property of `three-d-box :hover` on css paart must be hidden when window is resized to 700px.The navigation bar code is below;

```js
$('.block-menu').find('a').each(function(){

  var el = $(this),
       elText = el.text();
  
  el.addClass("three-d");
  el.append('<span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box"><span class="front">'+elText+'</span><span class="back">'+elText+'</span></span>');
});
```

```css
.container {
   width: match-parent;
   padding: 12px ;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

a {
  color: #fc0;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.block-menu {
 width:fit-content; 
  height:fit-content;
}

.block-menu li {
 display: inline-block;
}

.block-menu li a {
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Passion One', Arial, sans-serif;
 font-smoothing: antialiased;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
 overflow: visible;
  width:fit-content;
 height: fit-content;
 font-size: 1.6vw;
 padding: 15px 10px;               
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                margin-top:1px;
                margin-bottom:1px;
}
.three-d {
 perspective: 200px;
 transition: all .07s linear;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}
 .three-d:hover .three-d-box, 
 .three-d:focus .three-d-box {
  transform: translateZ(-25px) rotateX(90deg);
 }

.three-d-box {
 transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
 transform: translatez(-25px);
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 pointer-events: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.front {
 transform: rotatex(0deg) translatez(25px);
}

.back {
 transform: rotatex(-90deg) translatez(25px);
 color: #ffe7c4;
}

.front, .back {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 border-radius:15%;
 background: black;
 padding: 15px 10px;
 color: white;
 pointer-events: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.back {
  background: #d05ce8;
}
```

```html
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>   

<div id="navbox">
<div class="container" id="navbar">

<ul class="block-menu"><b>
<li ><a href="gifts.html">Gifts Corner</a></li>
<li ><a href="activity.html">Our activities</a></li>
<li ><a href="inspire.html">Inspiration</a></li>
<li ><a href="edu.html">Education</a></li>
<li ><a href="abUS.html">About us</a></li>
</ul></b>
</div>
```

Comment: You could just use a media query. Something like `@media (min-width: 700px) { }` and put there your  `.three-d:hover .three-d-box` animation if you don't want to use it below that screen width.